# Open redirect fortify issue in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, fortify

I am working on .net web application with 4.0 framework. I was working on Open Redirect issues where I found that we need encode our `Querystring` parameter values.

my sample code

```
//Open redirect fortify issue

 string id= Request.QueryString["id"];

 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
 -- here the issue
 Response.Redirect(webform.aspx?id=" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(id));
```

Can you please help?

Comment: "Encode" how?  What exactly is the problem?  What have you tried and what isn't working?

Comment: just i'm redirect one page to another page when i put the code in hp fortify on demand i got an issue for open redirect so i try to use encode but working

Comment: "I got an issue" doesn't really describe the problem.  Neither does "not working".  *How* is your code "not working"?  What incorrect thing does your code do?  If some third party tool or person is telling you that your working code is in some way incorrect, then you're going to need to ask them what they recommend.

Comment: ya they recommend for int values not string

Comment: That still doesn't explain what the problem is, or why you've now modified the question to use an entirely different encoding.  Try to understand that nobody here is working on the same project as you or knows what you're talking about.  You need to be clear and complete and your description of the problem.  Short, cryptic comments don't accomplish much.

Comment: @David- Google "open redirect" :)

Comment: @weir: I'm familiar with an open redirect, but that's not what this code is doing.  The redirect here isn't forwarding the user to an inserted URL, it's just putting a value on the query string.  It sounds like the OP is using some kind of code analysis tool to look for possible exploits.  I suspect that tool offers *a little* more information than "here the issue".  The original code URL-encoded the value, which I would recommend.  The OP has changed it to HTML-encoding (and a syntax error) for some unknown reason...

Comment: Agreed on all counts, notably that the URL encoding was better than the HTML encoding. Given OP's mention of int rather than string I do think int.TryParse is better still.

Answer (score -1):

```
string id= Request.QueryString["id"];

int safeId;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id) && int.TryParse(id, out safeId))
  Response.Redirect("webform.aspx?id=" + safeId.ToString());
```

EDIT: Not sure why someone down-voted this answer, but perhaps I should point to the OP's comment that "they recommend for int values not string".

Comment: your right this for int values right if the id  is string values means                     for eg   string id= "12345G"